# "Imports statement is unnecessary" but then "ReportDocument is undefined"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to use CrystalReports in my project. I have installed it on my computer and added `CrystalDecisions.CrustalReports.Engine`,`CrystalDecisions.ReportSource` and `CrystalDecisions.Shared` to my references, yet when I enter

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
```

At the top of my code, I get told both "doesn't contain any public members or cannot be found" and then further down in my implementation, `Dim cr As New ReportDocument` returns a "Type ReportDocument is not defined"

As far as I know I have carried out all the required steps to include the CR library. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

To fix it, I went to the Solution Explorer, right clicked the project, clicked Add, then Reference, Extensions and unchecked CrystalDecisions.Shared and CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.  I then clicked OK.  Went back to Add, Reference, Extensions and added them back. Clicked OK and everything worked.

Hope it works for you.